# tilde and bar entangled into each other

Tags: tilde

[image]some times when we want to introduce two or more signs on top of a letter (for example tilde and bar signs over the letter u) they are entangled to each other  (especially when we convert it to PDF) which makes it hard to recognize the signs in the final PDF print. For example in the the following formula:

\tilde{\bar{u}}_i

when I convert the final output into PDF, the tilde and bar are not recognizable in the printed PDF.This is bothering me and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Looks fine to me. May be you're using some unusual fonts/packages? Then show a complete minimal example which doesn't show up properly.

Comment: They are showing fine when I use the GS view. But when I convert them to PDF, then they becomes nasty.

Comment: Can I attach a photo to show it?

Comment: You can attach an image to your question. But it'd be better if you show the code (and describe your workflow) which causes the entangling.

Comment: How are you compiling? Sounds like you use some intermediate file and don't directly compile to pdf? This is what I get from your code compiled with pdflatex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL0Gy.png

Comment: That's true. Now, I am pretty sure that the problem comes from printing. When I compile the Latex, I use GS view and to produce the PS file, Then I convert it to PDF and this problems happens.

Comment: This is while if I print to PDF instead of converting to PDF, this problem does not exist, however, the resolution is decreased (because I believe it is treated as a picture and not as a font any more)

Comment: No comment or suggestion? I have also attached a photo that shows the problem. What if I use the linux command PS2PDF and add some options to fix it?

Comment: compile your document with pdfLateX .

Comment: I did the pdflatex, this problem is solved. However, since my pictures all have eps format, it does not recognize them. If I can fix this problem, then it will be ok.

Comment: I think I could solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could solve the problem

There was a package used in the latex, I deactivated it and now the problem is gone. This is what I have deactivated:

\usepackage{mathptmx}